# How to negate a variable?

Tags: cobol

I have the below Working-storage variable in my program.

```
01  W-WRK.
    02  W-MNTH-THRSHLD      PIC S9(04).
```

I am using the below COMPUTE function to negate the value of W-MNTH-THRSHLD.

```
COMPUTE W-MNTH-THRSHLD OF W-WRK = 
               W-MNTH-THRSHLD OF W-WRK * -1.
```

I want to know if this approach is right or is there any alternative for the same?

Comment: That or subtract from zero etc

Comment: As Bill said, you could also use MULTIPLY -1 * W-WRK

Comment: The Intrinsic Function Absolute Value (ABS) isn't the same thing as negation, but depending upon what you're really after, I offer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, why are you using qualification (the `OF`)? That is only required if you have defined duplicate names. Why define duplicate names in the WORKING-STORAGE?

Secondly, unless you are using a very old COBOL compiler, you should only use the minimum required full-stops/periods in the `PROCEDURE DIVISION`. That is, one to terminate the paragraph/SECTION label, one to terminate a paragraph/SECTION. One to terminate the PROCEDURE DIVISION header. One to terminate a program (if a full-stop/period is not already there. Keeping extra full-stops/periods around makes it more difficult to copy code around. Put the full-stop/period on a line of its own, so no line of code has one, then you can't accidentally terminate a scope by copying a line of code with a full-stop/period to within a scope.

With those in mind, your code becomes:

```
       COMPUTE W-MNTH-THRSHLD       = W-MNTH-THRSHLD 
                                    * -1
```

Multiplication is slower than subtraction. So as Bruce Martin suggested:

```
       COMPUTE W-MNTH-THRSHLD       = 0 
                                    - W-MNTH-THRSHLD
```

I do it like this:

```
       SUBTRACT W-MNTH-THRSHLD      FROM 0 
         GIVING                     W-MNTH-THRSHLD-REV-SIGN
```

I dislike "destroying" a value just for the heck of it. If the program fails, I know what W-MNTH-THRSHLD contained, plus the meaningful name for the target field explains what the line does.

You could also `DIVIDE` (or `/` in COMPUTE), but that is even slower than MULTIPLY (or `*`).

Also bear in mind that conversions may be required, because you are doing arithmetic with a USAGE DISPLAY field. If you define your field as `BINARY` or `PACKED-DECIMAL` conversion is less likely for arithmetic. You won't lose by doing that, unless your compiler can deal with a USAGE DISPLAY in arithmetic without requiring conversion.

Note also, COMPUTE is not a function. COMPUTE is a verb, just a part of the language. "I am using COMPUTE" is sufficient, and not even necessary, as we can see that from the code.